# Docker Kill Container Randomly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I deploy my app with docker swarm. My server have 8GB of RAM

But docker do OOM kill on container randomly. But when I do free -h I have 1.4G free and 6.0G available. So I don't understand by docker need to kill those container?

Comment: `docker service logs` please

Comment: It killed randomly. So how can we know which service to logs?

Comment: anyone is better than nothing.

Comment: What's the actual `free` output?  If you run `dmesg` do you see the OOM-kill sequence there?

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to find and solve the problem? If yes, what was the solution? I am having the same problem, as describer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798348/docker-swarm-not-scheduling-containers-when-node-dies/63814874?noredirect=1. thanks