# Docker Swarm not scheduling containers when node dies

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm-mode

**EDIT**

NEVEMIND THIS QUESTION. I found that one of my services, which is using a [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet), was terminating the services marked as `Shutdown`. I've corrected the bug and have regained my trust in Docker and Docker Swarm.
Thank you Carlos for you help. My bad, my fault. Sorry for that!

I have 13 services configured on a docker-compose file and running in Swarm mode with one manager and two worker nodes.

[image]

Then I make one of the worker nodes unavailable by draining it

`docker node update --availability drain ****-v3-6by7ddst`

What I notice is that all the services that where running on the drained node are removed and not scheduled to the available node.
The available worker and manager nodes still have plenty of resources.. The services are simply removed.I am now down to 9 services

[image]

[image]

Looking at the logs I see stuff like bellow but repeated with different service ids

```
level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap."
level=error msg="Error getting service u68b1fofzb3nefpnasctpywav: service u68b1fofzb3nefpnasctpywav not found"
level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 021eda460c5744fd4d499475e5aa0f1cfbe5df479e5b21389ed1b501a93b47e1 possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
```

Then, for debug purposes I set my node back to available
`docker node update --availability active ****-v3-6by7ddst`

Then I try to balance some of the services to the newly available node. And this is the result.

[image]

I get the same error on the logs

```
level=error msg="Error getting service ****_frontend: service ****_frontend not found"
level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 6bb220c0a95b30cdb3ff7b577c7e9dec7ad6383b34aff85e1685e94e7486e3ea possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
msg="Error getting service l29wlucttul75pzqo2sgr0u9e: service l29wlucttul75pzqo2sgr0u9e not found"
```

On my docker-compose file I am configuring all my services like this. Restart policy is any.

```
  frontend:
    image: {FRONTEND_IMAGE}
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.lbswarm=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`${FRONTEND_HOST}`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"
        - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.docker.network=ingress"
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: ${FRONTEND_LIMITS_MEMORY}
          cpus: ${FRONTEND_LIMITS_CPUS}
        reservations:
          memory: ${FRONTEND_RESERVATION_MEMORY}
          cpus: ${FRONTEND_RESERVATION_CPUS}
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    networks:
      - ingress
```

Something fails while recreating services on different nodes, and even with only one manager/worker node I get the same result.

The rest seems to work fine. As an example, if I scale a service it works well.
[image]

### New Edit

Just did another test.

- This time I only have two services, traefik and front-end.
- One instance for traefik
- 4 instances for front-end
- two nodes (one manager and one worker)
- Drained worker node and front-end instances running on the drained node are moved to the manager node
- Activated back the worker node
- Did a `docker service update cords_frontend --force` and two instances of front-end are killed on the manager node and are placed running on the worker node.

So, with this test with only two services everything works fine.

Is there any kind of limit to the number of services and stack should have?

Any clues why this is happening?

Thanks

Hugo

Comment: Do those services show when you do a "docker service ls" or a "docker stack services <stackname>"?

Comment: Yes, sure. Why do you ask?

Comment: No specific reason, just trying to see if for some reason the drain removed the services but it seems like they are still there.  Have you tried removing the resource limits and reservations from the compose file to see if that makes a difference? Also have you tried using "docker events" and then trying to do the update to see what events get logged and if they provide more info on why they aren't coming up?

Comment: Hi again. Actually, after draining a node, services are removed. I started with 13 nodes and after draining the node, the number of services are down to 9. So, services die and are not recovered again.

Comment: Did you try “docker events”?  I would do it on both nodes when doing the drain so you can see what is happening when the services are being removed and what if anything is happening on the node they should come up on.

Comment: Just did that. Nothing interesting comes up.  I ran `docker service update cords_frontend --force` and this is what is written on the events `service update q2sxvfcreia142rith3g7z2qq (name=cords_frontend)`   then -->  `service update q2sxvfcreia142rith3g7z2qq (name=cords_frontend, updatestate.new=updating)` and finally ---> `service remove q2sxvfcreia142rith3g7z2qq (name=cords_frontend)`. Why is it removing my services? No idea!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be running into an issue with resource reservations.  You mention that the nodes available have plenty of resources, but the way reservations work, a service will not be scheduled if it can't reserve the resources specified, very important to note that this has nothing to do with how much resources the service is actually using. This means that if you specify a reservation you are basically saying that service will reserve that amount of resources and those resources are not available for other services to use. So if all your services have similar reservations you may be running into a situation where even though the node shows available resources, those resources are in fact reserved by the existing service.  So I would suggest you remove the reservations section and try it to see if that is in fact what is happening.

Comment: Tried removing all the reservation tags from my docker-compose file. Same behaviour. I don't think it is a case of reservations because I made sure that all the reserved memory and cores would not exceed the total capacity of each core. But thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: Given your last update where you specify that it works fine with just 2 services, I would try gradually adding more services and testing to see at what point it starts failing.  There is no limit that I know of in the number of services in a stack. I currently have a stack with over 30 services and I've had a node go down and all the services would automatically come up on other nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Also, when removing the reservation tags I assume you removed the stack and then redeployed, correct?

Comment: yep. And I could see, by doing `docker stats` that each service had a memory limit of 8GB, the machine RAM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I am still struggling with this.

As a recap, I have on docker stack with 13 services running in swarm mode with two nodes (manager+worker). Each node has 4 cores and 8GB of RAM (Ubuntu 18.04, docker 19.03.12).
If a node dies, or I drain a node, all the services running on this node die and are marked are `Removed`. If I simply run `docker service update front_end --force` the service also dies and is marked as removed.

Another important detail is, if I sum up all the reserved memory and cores from the 13 services I end up with 1.9 cores and 4GB of RAM, way bellow each of the nodes resources.

I don't see any out of memory on the containers, services or stack logs. Also, by using `htop` tool I can see that memory usage is using 647MB/7.79GB on Manager node and 2GB/7.79GB on the worker node.

This is what i tried so far:

- separated the 13 services into two different stacks. No luck.
- removed all the reservations tags from the compose files. No luck.
- tried running with 3 nodes. No luck.
- I was seeing this warning `WARNING: No swap limit support` so I followed the suggestions on this document on both nodes [enter link description here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities). No luck.
- Upped both node resources to 8 cores and 16BG of RAM. No luck.
- tried starting each service one at the time, and I noticed it starts behaving badly with 10 or more services. That is to say, everything works fine if I have up to 9 services running, after this I see the behaviour described above.

Also, I enabled docker's debug mode to see what was happening. Here are the outputs.

If I run `docker service update front_end --force` and front_end service dies, this is the output form `docker events`

```
service update k6a7go4uhexb4b1u1fp98dtke (name=frontend)
service update k6a7go4uhexb4b1u1fp98dtke (name=frontend, updatestate.new=updating)
service remove k6a7go4uhexb4b1u1fp98dtke (name=frontend)
```

logs from `journalctl -fu docker.service`

```
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="form data: {\"EndpointSpec\":{\"Mode\":\"vip\"},\"Labels\":{\"com.docker.stack.image\":\"registry.gitlab.com/devteam/.frontend:1.0.5\",\"com.docker.stack.namespace\":\"\",\"traefik.docker.lbswarm\":\"true\",\"traefik.docker.network\":\"net\",\"traefik.enable\":\"true\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints\":\"websecure\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule\":\"Host(`www.frontend.website`)\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver\":\"myhttpchallenge\",\"traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port\":\"80\"},\"Mode\":{\"Replicated\":{\"Replicas\":1}},\"Name\":\"frontend\",\"TaskTemplate\":{\"ContainerSpec\":{\"Image\":\"registry.gitlab.com/fdevteam/frontend:1.0.5@sha256:e9a0d88bc14848c3b40c3d2905842313bbc648c1bbf09305f8935f9eb23f289a\",\"Isolation\":\"default\",\"Labels\":{\"com.docker.stack.namespace\":\"f\"},\"Privileges\":{\"CredentialSpec\":null,\"SELinuxContext\":null}},\"ForceUpdate\":1,\"Networks\":[{\"Aliases\":[\"frontend\"],\"Target\":\"w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d\"}],\"Placement\":{\"Platforms\":[{\"Architecture\":\"amd64\",\"OS\":\"linux\"}]},\"Resources\":{},\"RestartPolicy\":{\"Condition\":\"any\",\"MaxAttempts\":0},\"Runtime\":\"container\"}}"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
...
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/tasks?filters=%7B%22_up-to-date%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%7B%22frontend%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="handleEpTableEvent UPD 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 R:{frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r frontend nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 10.0.1.73 10.0.1.74 [] [frontend] [e661c9f39097] true}"
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent START for frontend 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 p:0xc004a1f880 nid:w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d sKey:{nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 } deleteSvc:true"
level=debug msg="deleteEndpointNameResolution 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 frontend rm_service:false suppress:false sAliases:[frontend] tAliases:[e661c9f39097]"
level=debug msg="delContainerNameResolution 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r"
level=debug msg="6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r, 10.0.1.74, <nil>, true) rmServiceBinding sid:6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 "
level=debug msg="6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(tasks.frontend, 10.0.1.74, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 "
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent END for frontend 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=error msg="Error getting service frontend: service frontend not found"
level=debug msg="handleEpTableEvent DEL 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 R:{frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r frontend nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 10.0.1.73 10.0.1.74 [] [frontend] [e661c9f39097] true}"
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent START for frontend 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 p:0xc004a1f880 nid:w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d sKey:{nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 } deleteSvc:true"
level=debug msg="deleteEndpointNameResolution 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 frontend rm_service:true suppress:false sAliases:[frontend] tAliases:[e661c9f39097]"
level=debug msg="delContainerNameResolution 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r"
level=debug msg="6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend.1.lv7tjjaev45pvn0f7qtppb21r, 10.0.1.74, <nil>, true) rmServiceBinding sid:6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 "
level=debug msg="6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(tasks.frontend, 10.0.1.74, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 "
level=debug msg="6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend, 10.0.1.73, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:nnlg81dsspnj6oxip4iqwwjc3 "
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent END for frontend 6b20c2924ec1eafa20c27d572019207551819b10a2c4f8d0574f2e142274c745"
```

If the service does not die (that is the case with 9 or less services) this is the ouput:

```
service update n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc (name=frontend)
service update n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc (name=frontend, updatestate.new=updating)
service update n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc (name=frontend, updatestate.new=completed, updatestate.old=updating)
```

logs from `journalctl -fu docker.service`

```
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="form data: {\"EndpointSpec\":{\"Mode\":\"vip\"},\"Labels\":{\"com.docker.stack.image\":\"registry.gitlab.com/devteam/.frontend:1.0.5\",\"com.docker.stack.namespace\":\"\",\"traefik.docker.lbswarm\":\"true\",\"traefik.docker.network\":\"net\",\"traefik.enable\":\"true\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints\":\"websecure\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule\":\"Host(`www.frontend.website`)\",\"traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver\":\"myhttpchallenge\",\"traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port\":\"80\"},\"Mode\":{\"Replicated\":{\"Replicas\":1}},\"Name\":\"frontend\",\"TaskTemplate\":{\"ContainerSpec\":{\"Image\":\"registry.gitlab.com/devteam/.frontend:1.0.5@sha256:e9a0d88bc14848c3b40c3d2905842313bbc648c1bbf09305f8935f9eb23f289a\",\"Isolation\":\"default\",\"Labels\":{\"com.docker.stack.namespace\":\"\"},\"Privileges\":{\"CredentialSpec\":null,\"SELinuxContext\":null}},\"ForceUpdate\":3,\"Networks\":[{\"Aliases\":[\"frontend\"],\"Target\":\"w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d\"}],\"Placement\":{\"Platforms\":[{\"Architecture\":\"amd64\",\"OS\":\"linux\"}]},\"Resources\":{},\"RestartPolicy\":{\"Condition\":\"any\",\"MaxAttempts\":0},\"Runtime\":\"container\"}}"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
...
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/tasks?filters=%7B%22_up-to-date%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%7B%22frontend%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="handleEpTableEvent UPD e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 R:{frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo frontend n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc 10.0.1.32 10.0.1.46 [] [frontend] [f986fe859440] true}"
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent START for frontend e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 p:0xc005e1fa00 nid:w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d sKey:{n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc } deleteSvc:true"
level=debug msg="deleteEndpointNameResolution e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 frontend rm_service:false suppress:false sAliases:[frontend] tAliases:[f986fe859440]"
level=debug msg="delContainerNameResolution e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo"
level=debug msg="e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo, 10.0.1.46, <nil>, true) rmServiceBinding sid:e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 "
level=debug msg="e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(tasks.frontend, 10.0.1.46, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc "
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent END for frontend e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
...
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/tasks?filters=%7B%22_up-to-date%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%7B%22frontend%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="handleEpTableEvent DEL e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 R:{frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo frontend n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc 10.0.1.32 10.0.1.46 [] [frontend] [f986fe859440] true}"
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent START for frontend e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 p:0xc005e1fa00 nid:w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d sKey:{n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc } deleteSvc:true"
level=debug msg="deleteEndpointNameResolution e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 frontend rm_service:true suppress:false sAliases:[frontend] tAliases:[f986fe859440]"
level=debug msg="delContainerNameResolution e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo"
level=debug msg="e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend.1.zeq4jz8kzle4c7vtzx5ofbrqo, 10.0.1.46, <nil>, true) rmServiceBinding sid:e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 "
level=debug msg="e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(tasks.frontend, 10.0.1.46, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc "
level=debug msg="e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98 (w7aqg3s).deleteSvcRecords(frontend, 10.0.1.32, <nil>, false) rmServiceBinding sid:n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc "
level=debug msg="rmServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent END for frontend e21b861c447ffd78bd2014744c13a146accd4600412c12b8cccfe3f3af4f0b98"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
...
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/tasks?filters=%7B%22_up-to-date%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%7B%22frontend%22%3Atrue%7D%7D"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
level=debug msg="handleEpTableEvent ADD 521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 R:{frontend.1.1v9ggahd87x2ydlkna0qx7jmz frontend n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc 10.0.1.32 10.0.1.47 [] [frontend] [3671840709bb] false}"
level=debug msg="addServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent START for frontend 521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 p:0xc004a1ed80 nid:w7aqg3stebnmk5c5pbhgslh2d skey:{n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc }"
level=debug msg="addEndpointNameResolution 521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 frontend add_service:true sAliases:[frontend] tAliases:[3671840709bb]"
level=debug msg="addContainerNameResolution 521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 frontend.1.1v9ggahd87x2ydlkna0qx7jmz"
level=debug msg="521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 (w7aqg3s).addSvcRecords(frontend.1.1v9ggahd87x2ydlkna0qx7jmz, 10.0.1.47, <nil>, true) addServiceBinding sid:521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0"
level=debug msg="521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 (w7aqg3s).addSvcRecords(tasks.frontend, 10.0.1.47, <nil>, false) addServiceBinding sid:n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc"
level=debug msg="521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0 (w7aqg3s).addSvcRecords(frontend, 10.0.1.32, <nil>, false) addServiceBinding sid:n1wh16ru879699cpv3topcanc"
level=debug msg="addServiceBinding from handleEpTableEvent END for frontend 521ffeee31efe056900fb5a1fe73007c179594e964f703625cf3272eb14983c0"
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
...
level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.40/services/frontend?insertDefaults=false"
level=debug msg="error handling rpc" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = service frontend not found" rpc=/docker.swarmkit.v1.Control/GetService
```